# how to change inline css to free attributes

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I'm trying to change a au generated HTML code  exp :

```
<div class="intro editable" id="field_text">text <strong>text</strong> text <span style="text-decoration: underline;">text</span> <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 16px;">text </span></div>
<h2 id="field_subtitle" class="editable">sub-title</h2>
<ul>  
    <li id="bp1" class="editable"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #008000; font-size: 14px;">text text text </span></li> 
    <li id="bp2" class="editable"><ul><br />
            <li><span style="color: #008000;"><strong>text text text</strong></span></li><br />
            <li><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #ff0000;"><em>text text text</em> </span></li><br />
        </ul></li> 
    <li id="bp3" class="editable"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #00376f; font-size: 14px;">text text text text text text </span></li> 
</ul>
```

to HTML that can be read with Adobe AIR :

```
    span = font 
    strong = <b>
    text-decoration:underlinded = <u> 

   <span style="font-size:; color:#;">Text</span>
==>
    <font color=""><font size="">Text</font></font>
```

i'm working with some Regex code, but still don't get the good results :

```
    $output = str_replace("<span", "<font", $output);
    $output = str_replace("span>", "font>", $output);
    $output = str_replace("<strong", "<b", $output);
    $output = str_replace("strong>", "b>", $output);
$output = preg_replace("/<font(.*)text-decoration: underline;([^>]*)>(.*)<\/font>/", '<font $1 $2><u>$3</u></font>', $output);      
$output = preg_replace("/<font(.*)font-size:\s(.*)px;([^>]*)>(.*)<\/font>/", '<font $1 $3 size="$2" >$4</font>', $output);
$output = preg_replace("/<font(.*)color:\s(.*);([^>]*)>(.*)<\/font>/", '<font $1 $3 color="$2" >$4</font>', $output);
```

Any helps ! Thanks :)

Comment: just a little notice:  `<font>` is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: but this translate is  for Adobe AIR app not for HTML5

Comment: Ew, HTML and regex... good luck with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made it by regex ! yes i have parsed html with regex ...

> only me and chuck Norris can do it lol...

After that i have cleaned the Html code using DOMdocument, to formate then add some lost closing tags

Thanks